# How to read VGL (Volume Graphics format) files in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, dataset, artificial-intelligence

Is there a module for handling VGL (Volume Graphics format) files in python, if not, what would be another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

ctutils 0.3
This project provides a set of small utilities for processing data from CT scanners in a variety of formats. Currently, the supported formats are:
Xradia’s TXM format
Volume Graphics VGI+VOL format
Grayscale TIFF stacks (8-bit, 16-bit)
https://pypi.org/project/ctutils/

Comment: But they don't give any code to load an file